# Sun Fire v440 does not power on

Tags: power-supply-unit, sun

I have an old Sun Fire v440 server which was in working condition before a shutdown a few months ago.

Today I tried to power it on but nothing happens when I press the power button.

On both PSUs green led "Standby Available" is on, but "Power OK" is off.

Should "Power OK" led be on ?
How can I check if it's a faulty PSU or something else is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sun Fire V440 Server Parts Installation and Removal Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19088-01/v440.srvr/816-7729-10/816-7729-10.pdf)

> OK-to-Remove
>
> This blue LED lights when it is safe to remove and replace the power
>   supply. This LED is lit by ALOM command and only lights when the other
>   power supply is functioning correctly.
>
> Service Required
>
> This amber LED lights to indicate a power supply
>   fault. If a power supply Service Required LED is lit, the system
>   Service Required LED is also lit.
>
> Power OK
>
> This green LED is lit when the power supply is on and
>   outputting regulated DC power within specified limits.
>
> Standby Available
>
> This green LED is lit when AC input power is
>   present. This LED is lit when the corresponding AC cable is plugged
>   into a power source and the power supply is functioning correctly,
>   regardless of system power status.

Seems like there is another problem...